_fit_method for KNN gives KD-tree even though I'm working in a high dimensional spce
so since KNeighborsClassifier class in sklearn find the best algorithm depending on the values from fit method when using auto (which is the default), when accessing the algorithm using ._fit_method I get kd tree which makes no sense Since the dimensionality of my data is too high for it
I have 32 dimensions and 49720032 training data point, which does not satisfy the equation :
N>2^k
what are possible reason for that?

What version of sklearn? What metric are you using? // There's https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a63b021310ba13ea39ad3555f550d8aeec3002c5/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py#L607, but currently that looks like it shouldn't give KD-tree? But also I don't see any reference to your n>2^k.

the sklearn version is 1.0.2, if you mean distance metric it's the default, I tried it with  manhattan and same thing ,and I'm not sure what you exactly mean by reference here
